How to rename metrics using attributes in OpenTelemetry collector
I am using OpenTelemetry collector with the awsecscontainermetrics receiver, which creates multiple metrics with the same name, which are differentiated by attributes. I would like to use the carbon exporter to send them to a backend that doesn't support OpenTelemetry attributes, so, therefore, I need to rename the metrics so that I can distinguish between them.
Is it possible to rename metrics to include an attribute in the new metric name?
For example, if I had a task with 2 containers, container_a and container_b, then I would like to output 2 sets of container metrics so container.cpu.utilized becomes e.g. container.container_a.cpu.utilized and container.container_b.cpu.utilized
I have tried using {{attribute}} in the metricstransform processor but the attribute value doesn't get substituted in.
Here is my full config:
receivers:
  awsecscontainermetrics:
exporters:
  carbon:
    endpoint: graphite:2003
processors:
  filter:
    metrics:
      include:
        match_type: strict
        metric_names:
          - container.cpu.utilized

  metricstransform:
    transforms:
      - include: container.cpu.utilized
        action: update
        new_name: container-insights-new.telemetry.{{aws.ecs.task.family}}.{{container.name}}.cpu.utilized

service:
  pipelines:
      metrics:
          receivers: [awsecscontainermetrics]
          processors: [filter, metricstransform]
          exporters: [carbon]

